# DataTables how to cut string and add (...) and put the full string in tooltip

Tags: datatables

I use fine DataTables for my website.

In a few rows it can happens that the string is very very long (e.g. 500 to 1000 chars).

How to cut that at 20 signs, add "..." and put that in a tooltip?

(of course I know substring and know how to add a tooltip, I just want to know if there is a feature / option for me on datatables or on which event I can get the data and cut it and add a tooltip to the cell)

Comment: here some older solutions from the datatables forums, no idea if it is still working like that: [Thread 1](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30/modifying-cell-content-before-showing), [Thread 2](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2177/limit-width-of-table-or-cell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a *pure* `DataTables` solution but this can be achieved by a setting fixed column width (via CSS or DataTables options) combined with `text-overflow: ellipsis` on your table cells.

For `text-overflow` to work you also need to specify a fixed width, set `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap`:

```
.limited{
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;                   
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

To see the full cell content add it to the cell's `title` attribute:

```
<td class='limited' 
  title='Very long cell content which is to long for the cell but shown as a tooltip'>
  Very long cell content which is to long for the cell but shown as a tooltip
</td>
```

Which could look something like this:

[image: Screen shot showing text-overflow]

See the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) on `text-overflow` for more details.

---

Another option would be using DataTables [orthogonal data](http://www.datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data) feature. In contrast to just using `substring` to limit the cell content, this would allow you to keep the complete cell content searchable:

```
<td data-search='Very long cell content which is to long for the cell but shown as a tooltip' 
   title='Very long cell content which is to long for the cell but shown as a tooltip'>
   Very long cell content...
</td>
```

The output would be the same es above.

Answer (score 3):

I know that the question is already answered, but i would like to add this 
 datatable [plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/ellipsis) as an option for this exactly problem. There's a very good explanation of how it works and how to use it in this [blog post](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-02-26).

It's very simple to use, suppose that you need the text to get cut and only show 20 characters, you can use like this:

```
$("#yourTableSelector").dataTable({
    ... // other configurations
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: 0, // the target for this configuration, 0 it's the first column
        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis(20)
    }]

});
```

Just to clarify, this plugins requires DataTables 1.10+

Comment: hi... thanks for the solution. Is there any way to make the whole text in tooltip selectable without affecting the current functionality?