# jQuery Datatables Cannot adjust width (tried to manually put the options in the ColumnDefs too)

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

How can one adjust the width of a datatable jquery to accomodate a specific number of characters in a certain column's cells and ensure that the width of the column is just about the same size as the max allowed text size. 
In the case of having more than the required number of characters, I am using a text ellipsis property. The concern however is the part where I cannot adjust the width of the datatable columns at all. I have added the CSS properties of    table-layout: fixed, word-wrap: break-word as well

```
  $("#" + tableName + "Table").DataTable( {
        "columnDefs" :[{
              className: "toolTipClass",
              "targets" : TOOLTIP_COLUMNS
         },{
               width: "10sem", "targets": 0
         });
```

**EDIT** FOUND A SIMILAR QUESTION HERE:
[DataTables how to cut string and add (...) and put the full string in tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752975/datatables-how-to-cut-string-and-add-and-put-the-full-string-in-tooltip)

Comment: Show us what you tried(source code) so far please :)

Comment: Sure, sorry about that

Comment: for setting width use em, px or % as unit.

Comment: I tried using the em, px or % as unit but does not make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED THE ISSUE (There is a plugin that does the job):
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/ellipsis